# Avoid add same data with many-to-many relationship jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have scenario, a Book could have one Category and belong to multi Author. A Category could have a lot of Books. Author could belong to a lot of Books.

So,

1. `Book` to `BookCategory` is `many-to-one`
2. `Book` to `Author` and `Author` to `Book` is `many-to-many` (in `book_author` table)
3. `BookCategory` to `Book` is `one-to-many`

I could do saving (with below code) new book with the author and also the category. But, the problem are:

1. If I did not check whether the author already exist in `Author` table, the same author will inserted again into `Author` table
2. If I check whether same author already exist in `Author` table, then omit the author from the list, how `book_author` table would know if the book have relationship with already exist author?

Here are how I declare the entity and the service:

**BookDto**

```
public class BookDto {
    private String title;
    private String year;
    private Set<AuthorDto> author;
    private String category;
}
```

**AuthorDto**

```
public class AuthorDto {
    private String name;
    private String address;
}
```

**Book**

```
@Entity(name = "book")
@Table(name = "book", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})})
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "year", nullable = false)
    private String year;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
      name = "book_author",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Author> author;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) 
    private BookCategory category;
}
```

**Author**

```
@Entity(name = "author")
@Table(name = "author", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})})
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false)
    private String address;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Book> book;
}
```

**BookCategory**

```
@Entity(name = "book_category")
@Table(name = "book_category")
public class BookCategory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "category", nullable = false)
    private String category;
}
```

**BookServiceImpl**

```
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {
    public BookDto save(BookDto bookDto) throws Exception {
        try {
            Book book = new Book();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(bookDto, book, "author", "category");
            BookCategory bookCategory = bookCategoryDao.findByCategory(bookDto.getCategory());

            Set<Author> dataAuthor = new HashSet<Author>();
            Set<AuthorDto> dataAuthorDto = new HashSet<AuthorDto>();
            bookDto.getAuthor().iterator().forEachRemaining(dataAuthorDto::add);

            for (AuthorDto authorDto : dataAuthorDto) {
                Author author = new Author();
                /** 
                 * Problem is:
                 * 1. If I did not check whether the author already exist in
                 * Author table, the same author will inserted again into Author table
                 * 2. If I check whether same author already exist in Author table, then omit
                 * the author from the list, how book_author table would know if
                 * the book have relationship with already existed author?
                 * */
                BeanUtils.copyProperties(authorDto, author);
                dataAuthor.add(author);
            }

            book.setAuthor(dataAuthor);
            book.setCategory(bookCategory);
            bookDao.save(book);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any help would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: If an entity has a relationship to an existing entity then you fetch that Entity form the database and set that as the target of the relationship.

Comment: @AlanHay could you give me pseudo code about "set that as the target of the relationship" based on what I've done so far, please?

Comment: ????If the entity is in the database then load it and add it to the set. `book.getAuthors().add(someExistingAuthorEntity)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I did not check whether the author already exist in Author table, the same author will inserted again into Author table

Correct. Which leads to the conclusion that if you don;t want duplicates, you *should* check whether the author already exists, whatever your business definition of 'the same' author is.

> If I check whether same author already exist in Author table, then omit the author from the list, how book_author table would know if the book have relationship with already exist author?

Well, don't omit it then. Look it up instead. Assuming your definition of the same author is 'the author with the same name', just add the following method to `DataAuthorRepository` (or whatever you called it):

```
Optional<Author> findByNameIgnoreCase(String name)
```

And then, in `BookServiceImpl`, simply do the following:

```
for (AuthorDto authorDto : dataAuthorDto) {
    Author author = dataAuthor.findByNameIgnoreCase(authorDto.getName())
    .orElseGet(() -> {
        Author newAuthor = new Author();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(authorDto, newAuthor);
        return newAuthor;
    });
    dataAuthor.add(author);
}
```